# T-SQL puzzler - given a cell in an N-dimensional space, return the cells that are inline with the given cell along each axis

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The cells in an N-dimensional space are modelled with the 2 tables below. A script is needed that takes a single cell (by CellID) and returns all the other cells that are "inline" with the given cell along each axis (including itself).

For example, suppose the space has 3 dimensions (X, Y, Z) and X has 2 positions, Y has 2 and Z has 3. If the cell with coordinates {1,1,1} is given, the result should be:

```
+----------+---------+
| AxisCode |  Cell   |
+----------+---------+
| X        | {1,1,1} |   <- showing coordinates for clarity, but should be CellID
| X        | {2,1,1} |
| Y        | {1,1,1} |
| Y        | {1,2,1} |
| Z        | {1,1,1} |
| Z        | {1,1,2} |
| Z        | {1,1,3} |
+----------+---------+
```

I have spent hours on this and only come up with queries that are hard-coded for a specific number of dimensions ....

Please note:
**Changing the schema of the 3 tables is not an option!
The script has to work for N dimensions, and should not involve loops or cursors.**

Compatibility must be MS SQL 2008 R2

Any ideas gratefully received!

```
create table dbo.Cells(
    CellID int not null,
    CellValue int not null,
    constraint PK_Cells primary key (CellID)
    )

create table dbo.AxisPositions(
    AxisCode char(1) not null,      -- X, Y, Z etc
    PositionOnAxis int not null,    -- 1, 2, 3, 4 etc
    constraint PK_AxisPositions primary key (AxisCode, PositionOnAxis)
    )

create table dbo.CellAxes(
    CellID int not null,
    AxisCode char(1) not null,      -- X, Y, Z etc
    PositionOnAxis int not null,    -- 1, 2, 3, 4 etc
    constraint PK_CellAxes primary key (CellID, AxisCode),
    constraint FK_CellAxes_Cells foreign key (CellID) references Cells(CellID),
    constraint FK_CellAxes_AxisPositions foreign key (AxisCode, PositionOnAxis) references AxisPositions(AxisCode, PositionOnAxis)
    )

-- Example data

insert Cells (CellID, CellValue)
values (1, 67), (2, 45), (3, 0), (4, 4), (5, 78), (6, 213), (7, 546), (8, 455), (9, 12), (10, 67), (11, 4), (12, 5)

insert AxisPositions (AxisCode, PositionOnAxis)
values ('X', 1), ('X', 2), ('Y', 1), ('Y', 2), ('Z', 1), ('Z', 2), ('Z', 3)

insert CellAxes (CellID, AxisCode, PositionOnAxis)
values  (1, 'X', 1), (1, 'Y', 1), (1, 'Z', 1),
        (2, 'X', 2), (2, 'Y', 1), (2, 'Z', 1),
        (3, 'X', 1), (3, 'Y', 2), (3, 'Z', 1),
        (4, 'X', 2), (4, 'Y', 2), (4, 'Z', 1),
        (5, 'X', 1), (5, 'Y', 1), (5, 'Z', 2),
        (6, 'X', 2), (6, 'Y', 1), (6, 'Z', 2),
        (7, 'X', 1), (7, 'Y', 2), (7, 'Z', 2),
        (8, 'X', 2), (8, 'Y', 2), (8, 'Z', 2),
        (9, 'X', 1), (9, 'Y', 1), (9, 'Z', 3),
        (10, 'X', 2), (10, 'Y', 1), (10, 'Z', 3),
        (11, 'X', 1), (11, 'Y', 2), (11, 'Z', 3),
        (12, 'X', 2), (12, 'Y', 2), (12, 'Z', 3)
```

Comment: i'm confused as to what makes them 'inline'

Comment: @Randy - it means - if you started at the given cell and walked outwards along each dimension in turn, what are the cells you would visit?

Comment: Why don't you visit {2,2,1}, {2,1,2}, or {1, 2, 2} in your example answer? Its been forever since I had to do math ;-)

Comment: @NWest, because those cells are on diagonals to {1,1,1}

Comment: I was actually more surpised by the lack of `{3,1,1}` and `{1,3,1}`, given the presence of `{1,1,3}`.

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin - X & Y dimensions have only 2 positions, but Z has 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select x.AxisCode, a2.CellID
from CellAxes a1
inner join CellAxes a2 on a2.AxisCode = a1.AxisCode
inner join CellAxes x on x.CellID = a1.CellID
where (a1.AxisCode = x.AxisCode or a1.PositionOnAxis = a2.PositionOnAxis)
and a1.CellID = @CellID -- Cell to match against
group by x.AxisCode, a2.CellID
having count(*) = (select count(distinct AxisCode) from CellAxes where CellID = @CellID)
```

Comment: Looks like this will work for small dimensions. I would be concerned about temp space if you start to increase the number or size of dimensions - that inner + inner join yields ~1296 rows before filtering , starting with only 36 rows of data.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your original two tables in your question, you can write dyanamic SQL to create columns that you can then use to compare with whatever you are using to define "inline".

```
-- Build list of column values to pivot
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(1000);
SELECT @cols =
STUFF((SELECT N'],[' + axiscode
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT axiscode FROM CellAxes) AS O(axiscode)
       ORDER BY axiscode
       FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 2, '') + N']';

SELECT @cols;

-- Build dynamic SQL query for pivoting   
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000);
SET @sql =
N'WITH pivotedData AS (SELECT CellID, ' + @cols +
N'FROM CellAxes ' +
N'PIVOT ' +
N'(MAX(PositionOnAxis) FOR AxisCode IN (' + @cols + N')) AS P)' + 
N'SELECT * from pivotedData'
-- Modify this query with a generated WHERE clause that defines what "inline" means.
;

EXEC(@sql);
```

Note that @BillKarwin is correct - there is not a safe recommended way to do this with straight SQL, since you are *storing your schema in your data*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your definition of 'inline', this should be an algorithm to get you to the solution:

1. Store each cell as a vector.
2. Compare all these vectors with the vector of your starting cell
3. All cells whose vector only shows a single difference are 'inline'

Answer (score 0):

For the record - I also posted this on [SQL Server Central and got some alternative solutions](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1514358-392-1.aspx) - worth checking if you are interested.